# Zip files content are not indexed with extractrequesthandler

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I am indexing zip files using ExtractRequestHandler. while indexing zip files. it only show file names with zip archives.

I tried with solr 4.2, 4.3, 3.6.2. but it doesn't seems to work. I want to index content along with file names.

any solution ?

Comment: Have you attached a recursing parser to the ParseContext you give to Tika? If not, try that, as Tika won't recurse into embedded resources (eg zips) without one being given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr currently does not index the zip file contents but just the file names.
I had raised an JIRA [SOLR-2416](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2416) for the same and a patch is attached with the JIRA.
This should allow you to index the zip file contents as well.
This JIRA is for Solr Cell and there is other one for DIH also.

Comment: I looked over your reported & issues and patches. and Solr svn you suggested to work with on some links. Would you please clear out how to apply this patch ??

Comment: you need to checkout the trunk code .. and use svn plugin to apply the patch. Once applied you need to rebuild the Solr artifacts and use those.

Comment: Okay let me try ! Thank you :)

Comment: Which Svn branch I should checkout ? http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/<branch>  ??

Comment: it looks very strange Because I am already using tika 1.4 latest release with solr 4.4. Which files or jar files exactly need changes. Please will you explain in brief ?

Comment: check the Solr patch. If basically a diff file. Check the Java file and just copy the code into the checked out branch/trunk and compile the source again.

Comment: which jar I need to rebuild ? I mean where is this file ExtractingDocumentLoader.java is actually ?

Comment: solr-cell jar must have the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34378/discussion-between-user2475624-and-jayendra)

Comment: applying patch result in follwing error :- 
Hunk #1 FAILED at 182.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file

Comment: The patch is a year old so may not apply on the current branch. You can directly modify the source code and rebuild solr. that would be quick.

Comment: I added the line:- context.set(Parser.class, parser); and now trying to build via ant dist command ? is it right way or any quick way to build sor ?

Comment: yup. its right. build the Solr. Then you can use the Solr Cell jar generated by the build.

Comment: I am Stucked with this. Ivy is throwing error "Impossible to resolve dependencies resolve failed !"